# OpenXml two column on selected paragraph

Tags: openxml

I am using officegen in node js to create docx file pragmatically. It is using openxml to create document.I want to create two column on on selected or specified  paragraph.

I use the following code.But it make whole document two column.

```
<w:sectPr>
<w:cols w:num="2" w:space="720"/>
</w:sectPr>
```

The link I followed http://officeopenxml.com/WPsectionCols.php

Comment: Did you find the solution?